# Exclude specific urls from http to https permanent redirect rule

Tags: url-rewrite-module

I've got the following redirect rule below to force all http traffic to https. However, we need to serve some pages that have a problem displaying in https and we need to force them to be http until we can get them updated to work under https.

```
  <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>

    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

One thing all these pages have in commons in that "/SSLA/" is part of the url. I'm not the rewrite guru I would like to be, but there are a couple of potential ways I can think of to fix this:

a) Somehow update this rule to exclude urls with "/SSLA/".

B) Add a rule before this rule that catches anything with "/SSLA/" and redirects to http if it's going to https and (either in the same rule or a separate rule?) also does nothing for http requests but stops processing so it doesn't hit this global http to https redirect rule.

Problem is, I'm not great with either regex or rewrite rules so I'm not quite sure how to accomplish either of those solutions (actually not even sure even either are the "proper" way to handle this).

So... please help! :)

EDIT: I should note that I have updated the c# code to redirect to http for these pages, but of course that causes a loop with the above rule. But I just point this out to say that all I *need* is for the redirect rules not to force http requests for pages with "/SSLA" to https since the code will redirect any such https requests to http. But if it's a trivial matter to also have the redirect rule force https requests with "/SSLA/" in them to http then I could remove the c# code that does the same.

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
<match url="((?!SSLA).)*" />
```

insteed

```
<match url=".*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use two rewrite rules:

1. For redirecting HTTPS -> HTTP for `SSLA/*` pages
2. For redirecting HTTP -> HTTPS for non `SSLA/*` pages.

Check my example below how I am filtering `SSLA` and `non SSLA` pages

```
    <rule name="Redirect to http SSLA" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^SSLA" />
       <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^SSLA" nagate="true" />
       <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```